# Async function blocks another requests in flask

Tags: python, flask, asynchronous, async-await

I have a small flask application in which I want to run async function on start-up, but at the same time another requests stop working. Maybe you know where am I wrong?

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
from waitress import serve
import os
from os import path

import json


import asyncio
import time
from scraper import scrap


DEBUG = True


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
CORS(app)


@app.route('/api/v1/request', methods=['POST'])
def process_order():
   #some code...


async def get_new_prices():
    print('async started')
    start = time.time()
    res = await scrap()
    end = time.time() - start
    print(res, end)



asyncio.run(get_new_prices())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: What does `scrap()` do?

Comment: Return an array

Comment: How does it build the array? I see it's from a module called `scraper`. Does it scrape websites?

Comment: Yes, it scraps data from my website and return an array

Comment: The await keyword means that the program stops until the scrap() returns. What exactly do you want the program to do? Run other requests in parallel?

Comment: You are right, I want to run other requests in parallel